# Mysql: maximum number of columns in ORDER BY clause?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, street, street_type, house
FROM table
WHERE street LIKE '%Ololo%'
ORDER BY city, street, street_type, CHAR_LENGTH(house), house
```

Found that `CHAR_LENGTH(house)` doesn't sort by it if placed on 4th position in ORDER BY. It starts to sory by `CHAR_LENGTH(house)` only if it's placed on 1..3 position. `city, street, street_type` all contain the same data in this example. Tried to CONCAT first columns in ORDER BY: doesn't help. `house` contains chars that's why I used `CHAR_LENGTH(house), house`

Comment: What error does mysql return?

Comment: Sorry. Corrected. All used columns are: city, street, street_type.

Comment: No error. Just sorts incorrectly: small, then large, then small again. All are varchars. House contains chars.

Comment: Can you post a few rows of sample data?

Comment: I user term *work* which is incorrect. Correctly to say: it's *not sorting*. Sorry.

Comment: Can you create an example on SQLFiddle that shows this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If `house` is `char`, try `CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(house))` to remove trailing spaces

Otherwise, it means that `city, street, street_type` are actually different: these are breaking the sort. When it goes back to short again, one of these changes

Comment: Doesn't help. It works withut TRIM if placed on 3rd position.

Comment: @michaelloop: then my 2nd case applies. city, street, street_type are actually different:

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just made `DISTINCT street_type` and found thay it gives two street_types... but they look the same for me. Now I'm trying to realize what the difference in 2 words. No spaces. Same chars. Thank you.

Comment: You could have a normal space vs a "hard space" or some UTF encoding thing where the "same" letter are different code points